# Email GitLab issue to Comments section

Tags: email, gitlab

Does anyone know if it is possible to send out an email to users and Cc a GitLab issue so that the email will show up in the comments section of the issue?

I know other applications have the ability to do this. Trello for example has an email that can be included. MS Teams has the same thing where an email address can be provided to include the contents of the email in a Teams thread.

If this is possible can someone provide me with an example of how that email address should be constructed?

Thanks.